# Checking divs for a specific class

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the class name on divs where a specific class name exists.

The problem I'm finding is that if a class name doesn't exist on a div the browser throws up an error.

```
function cardUnfocus() {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
       if (document.getElementById(divs[i]).className != null) {
           if (document.getElementById(divs[i]).className == "container_selected")
                document.getElementById(divs[i]).className = "container";
        }
    }
}
```

What is an elegant way to check if a class exists? (not using jQuery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList):

```
element.classList.contains('name-of-class');
```